# Showing Data and Image for Form Edit in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my car models in a edit form which users can edit and delete a car.
When user clicks on edit they could see the car, model, year, price on the edit form and make new changes and submit.  I want the uploaded image to show up and edit as well. I know form_input() wont bring the image to show.  I tried everything but it wont display in my edit form.  Here is my code,  thanks!

```
controller:
public function input($id = 0) {

$this->load->helper('form');  
$this->load->helper('html');    
$this->load->model('model_users');

/*
if($this->input->post('submit')) {
    $this->model_users->entry_insert();
}
$data = $this->books_model->general();
*/

   if((int)$id > 0) {
     $query = $this->model_users->get($id);
  $data['fid']['value'] = $query['id'];
  $data['fcar_make']['value'] = $query['car_make'];
  $data['fcar_model']['value'] = $query['car_model'];
  $data['fcar_year']['value'] = $query['car_year'];
  $data['fcar_lease']['value'] = $query['car_lease'];
  $data['fcar_payment']['value'] = $query['car_payment'];
  $data['fimgpath']['value'] = $query['imgpath'];

}


if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {          
$this->load->view('edit_car',$data);    
}

else {
redirect('main/restricted');
}


 }


Model:

function get($id) {

        $this->db->where(array('id'=>$id));
        $query = $this->db->get('cars');
        return $query->row_array();
    }


view

<tr>
  <td>Car Lease:</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="textbox" tabindex="6" name = "<?php echo form_input($fcar_lease); ?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Car Payment:</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="textbox" tabindex="6" name = "<?php echo form_input($fcar_payment); ?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Car Image:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name=""<?php echo form_input($fimgpath); ?>" size="20" /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't show image or image path in file upload field, instead of that just show the image underneath the file upload field (like you display it in the front-end) and if user re uploads the image, delete existing one, upload new one and update the image name in the DB.

Additionally you can give a delete button to delete the image on the same interface (may underneath the current image).

Comment: Edit in the sense? they want to upload new one instead of existing or to do image editing?

Comment: btw, i put this in my code, but all of the images are coming up foreach($images as $row)
     {
      ?>   
     
     <img src = "/autoline/<?php echo ltrim($row->imgpath, '/'); ?>" >
     <?php $fimgpath; ?>
   <?php }
     
    ?>

Comment: Can user upload multiple images?

Comment: for example, if they click on edit Acura, on the edit car page acura car comes with car lease, car year and only the acura image

Comment: then it should show only the Acura image only no, have a delete button to the image, or if user re-upload the image replace existing one. it's simple no, isn't it?

Comment: oh, your saying have a delete button next to the image.  I get that but how can I show that image to show up for specifically that car